# How to print bold text in terminal?

Tags: command-line, echo

```
var=apple
echo " the $var is a fruit "
```

I want to print the apple is a fruit in bold
I tried this

```
echo $'\e[32;1m the $var is a fruit\e[0m\e ;'
```

but not working, please help me.

Comment: how does this relate to ubuntu?

Comment: Please improve your question: "*i need to print this*" is not a good title, and "*not working*" not a good error description. Also, you want to print bold, but your example is printing green+bold.

Answer (score 1):

Variable expansion does not work in single quotes.

So either you can end the quote and start again (but I think this is very unreadable):

```
echo $'\e[32;1m the '"$var"$' is a fruit\e[0m'
```

Or simply use `echo -e`:

```
echo -e "\e[32;1m the $var is a fruit\e[0m"
```

Even better option would be to use `printf`:

```
printf '\e[32;1m the %s is a fruit\n\e[0m' "$var"
```